# Triggered Send via API sends blank email (no personalization, empty fields)

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, dataextensions, triggered-send

We're building a **Purchase Confirmation** email and we can successfully trigger an email, but the personalized content is blank - for example, Order Number, Ship Date, Product Name, etc are all blank.

The data appears fine in the **Triggered Data Extension**. Previewing the email shows the email as fully populated.  I feel like there's a step missing somewhere... how do we get the data from the Triggered Data Extension to display in the email??

The data in the data extension is sent in the **API post** as well.

Some sample API code (note: I'm NOT an API Dev, so this is all foreign to me)

```
            var wsApiAttributes = new List<WSApiEmail.WSApiAttribute>();

        //order info
        wsApiAttributes.Add(new WSApiEmail.WSApiAttribute
        {
            Name = "ordernumber",
            Value = "Test10004" //must unique even for testing
        });
        wsApiAttributes.Add(new WSApiEmail.WSApiAttribute
        {
            Name = "orderdate",
            Value = "2019-01-12"
        });
        wsApiAttributes.Add(new WSApiEmail.WSApiAttribute
        {
            Name = "shipdate",
            Value = "2019-01-14"
        });
        wsApiAttributes.Add(new WSApiEmail.WSApiAttribute
        {
```

Comment: Have you made edits to the email since you started the trigger? It may be as simple as pausing, publish changes and restarting.

Comment: @Gortonington -- Let's add this to my tab -- I now owe you two drinks.  It's always the simple answers, isn't it?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it easier to find for anyone else experiencing this issue, I have turned my comment into an answer.

When editing an email that is used in a Triggered Send Definition (TSD) you will need to pause, publish changes and then restart it for any of these updates to be included inside your TSD.

This includes, but is not limited to, changes inside the email's HTML/scripting as well as changes inside externally referenced content areas used in the email.